# v4l2loopback device not working with gstreamer

Tags: kernel, 20.04, video, gstreamer, v4l

I'm on Ubuntu 20.4.1. I followed the instructions on https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback e.g. `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback` to set up a loopback device which I then can also find under `ls /dev/video*` as `/dev/video2`. But when I try to pipe something into it using gstreamer with this command `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2` I get the following error

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: Device '/dev/video2' is not a output device.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(636): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0:
Capabilities: 0x85208000
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Does anyone know how I could debug this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is to upgrade v4l2loopback to last version which is 0.12.5. It is fully detailled by developer and tested by me in [this ticket](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/370) on Github.

The only slight issue is that v0.12.5 is not officially part of 20.04. It comes only with 20.10. So, some ad hoc procedure is required: 2 different ones are proposed in the ticket

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: You're welcome! Didier